# Захламление кода Delphi

Tags: delphi, property

Можно ли избавится от захламления кода лишними функциями при написании класса?

```
SomeClass1 = class
  SomeValue : Record
    z:integer;
  end;
end;

SomeClass2 = Class
  SomeRec   : SomeClass1;
end;

SomeClass3
Private
  MyClass : SomeClass2;
Public
  Property SomeVal : integer read MyClass.SomeRec.SomeVal.z;//<<<Тут ошибка
End;
```

Обязательно ли в SomeClass3 делать доп функцию для чтения SomeVal.z? или можно поедить сие хитрой конструкцией прямо в описании Property SomeVal

```
SomeClass3
Private
  Function ReadSomeVal:integer;
  MyClass : SomeClass2;
Public
  Property SomeVal : integer read ReadSomeVal;
End;
implementation
Function SomeClass3.ReadSomeVal;
 Begin
   Result:=MyClass.SomeRec.SomeVal.z;
 end;
```

Comment: Да, обязательно. Так правильнее со всех точек зрения.

> Result := MyClass.SomeRec.SomeVal.z;

А не страшно, что внезапно окажется, что `MyClass = nil`, и обращение к проперти закончится AV?

Comment: Нет не страшно) SomeClass3 является Ребёнком для MyClass и служит для сокращеня имен переменных из MyClass.. Сделано для упрощения скриптования(использую TPSScript) дабы обращение из скрипта шло вида wnd(wName).SomeVal заместо MyClass(LinkMyClass).SomeClass.SomeClass.SomeVal.Val;

Comment: Чесно сказать вопрос правильности это последнее что меня интересует при построении такого велосипеда ;) само наличие SomeClass3 уже неправильно)

Comment: Это печально. Давайте в ответ, приму его чтоли.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delphi в любом случае ожидает `Field or method` после `read`, так что вставить туда выражение вам никто не даст.

Comment: Пока не закрыл, можно ли делать так?
Function SomeFunc(s:String):boolean;
Property SomeProp : boolean read SomeFunc('1');

Comment: нет, потому что ожидается `Field or method`, т.е. идентификатор метода или поля, а не вычисляемое выражение (коим является вызов функции).

Никто ведь не удивляется, что нельзя написать такое:

    Property SomeProp : integer read 5+3;

Comment: Ну я допустим негодую...и с удовольствием писал бы как показано выше)

Comment: Так форкните FreePascal Compiler и перепишите, как надо )

Answer (score 1):

Да, обязательно. Если Вы не хотите писать много гетеров в классе (хотя не понятно почему, это же автоген), то наверное можете сделать какой-нибудь универсальный геттер от индекса например. И либо хард код, или через интерефейсы реализовать. Но зачем?

```
PropertiesInterface = interface
  function GetIntegerValueByName(name:string):integer;
  function GetValueContainerByName(name:string):PropertiesInterface ;
end

SomeClass1 = class(PropertiesInterface)
  SomeValue : Record
    z:integer;
  end;
  function GetIntegerValueByName(name:string):integer;
  function GetValueContainerByName(name:string):PropertiesInterface ;
end;

SomeClass2 = Class(PropertiesInterface)
  SomeRec   : SomeClass1;
  function GetIntegerValueByName(name:string):integer;
  function GetValueContainerByName(name:string):PropertiesInterface ;
end;

SomeClass3
Private
  MyClass : SomeClass2;
Public
  Property SomeIntVal[name: string] : integer read GetIntVal
End;

implementation
//name VarName|VarName|
Function GetIntVal(name: string):integer;
var
   varList: array of string;
   i: integer;
   current_var: PropertiesInterface;
 Begin
   varList = name.Strip("|");//не помню есть ли такое в дельфи, но суть ясна?
   current_var = MyClass as PropertiesInterface;
   for i := 0 to Length(varList)-1 do
   begin
     current_var = current_var.GetValueContainerByName(varList[i]);
     if current_var = nil then 
       raise ENotFoundExeption;
   end;
   if current_var <> nil then
     result = current_var.GetIntegerValueByName(varList[Length(varList)-1])
   else
     raise ENotFoundExeption;
 end;
```

Comment: Невариант. условие описано четко) как сделать по другому я и так знаю(в другом места так и делаю), но хотелось  данный клас описать максимально коротко и "красиво"

Comment: C# ? :-) 

    public int SomeVal { get { return MyClass.some.other.vals;} }

К сожалению в object pascale так незя. Хотя может это и к лучшему, больше дисциплинирует. Можно имплементацию этих геттеров вынести в другой файл конечно. Не совсем понимаю зачем надо в описании класса видеть откуда он берёт данные проперти? На мой взгляд, верный путь - правильно именовать проперти, ну и сеттеры геттеры можно под дерективу {$I} вынести.

Comment: да, я тоже задумался, не съест ли компилятор анонимную функцию, так сказать in-place. Но нет, не съел. Оно и к лучшему: анонимные функции в дельфе весьма громоздки.

Comment: Да и это будет противоречить идеологии. Допустим имплементация у нас лежит в dll а в интерфейсе мы вдруг каким-то образом воткнули такое выражение - в итоге или линковщик с компилятором сойдут с ума, или программисты которые писали имплементацию, когда им посыпятся претензии что их код работает не так как надо. И, я уверен, они потом найдут того кудесника который подправил интерфейсную часть класса, и если уж до 105 не дойдёт то 116 точно будет :-)

Comment: Оу оу оу, все выше описано как я уже гдето говорил сделано лиш для удобной обработки скриптов на паскаль машинке.. ну не гоже пользователю знать иерархию классов у меня, ему хватит того к чему разрешено лезть, просто не хотелось городить кучу функций гетеров.

т.к. паскаль машинка сама втягивает класы на которые тыкнут пальцем и была попытка сделать такой велосипед, ну раз не судьба буду писать кучу гетеров...

Comment: @ToRcH565, так а паскаль машинку заапдейтить чтобы она это понимала?

Comment: Тут разговор не о том чтобы понимала, а о том что она втягивает реальный класс из паскалей, а втягивать 2 десятка классов(as is) нестоит) там много лишнего для пользователей, вот и пишу класс который обращается к существующим, думал сэкономить кучу кода такими вызовами проперти) ну да ладно) да и всю уже работает в том виде что хотелось, кроме лишнего кода)

Comment: Так а этот класс-обёртка вообще нужен в реальном коде?
И потом если пользователю не надо знать иерархию классов Ваших, то если в описании будут прямые ссылки - то и иерархию можно будет вытащить по ним. В случае с безопасностью, лень хороша только если всё запрещать, и лениииво по чуть чуть что то разрешать :-)

Comment: Ideafix в том что сам собираюсь чепятать часть програмки на этой паскаль машинке))) а так да, разрешаемс почуть чуть)))

Answer (score -2):

Извиняюсь. По теме, Я делаю так:

```
TMyClassAbstract = class
private
  function GetX: Integer;
  procedure SetX(Value: Integer);
  // ...
public
  property X: Integer read GetX write SetX;
  // ... и все другие свойства
end;

TMyClass = class (TMyClassAbstract)
// ..
```

т. е. все свойства Я скрываю в абстрактном класе

Comment: не о том речь

Comment: Извиняюсь. По теме, Я делаю так:

TMyClassAbstract = class
private
  function GetX: Integer;
  procedure SetX(Value: Integer);
  // ...
public
  property X: Integer read GeX write SetX;
  // ... и все другие свойства
end;



TMyClass = class (TMyClassAbstract)





т. е. все свойства Я скрываю в абстрактном класе

Comment: Мне не нужно их скрывать и не поверите раздел Private и все что в нем видно только при вызове из компонента\потомка. я хотел избавится от описания ф-ий, т.к. не считаю полезным кодом функции подобные begin result:=someclass.val; end;

Comment: >>раздел Private и все что в нем видно только при вызове из компонента\потомка
Нет. То что в нем видно только в границах модуля. Но мы же не собираемся напрямую обращаться к полю когда есть свойство? (а если и так то есть protected)  
  
Избавится от кода функций, конечно, не возможно. Могу лишь посоветовать использовать сокращение: Ctrl + Spase + propf (свойства для доступа к полю), Ctrl + Spase + propgs (через функи Get/Set), Ctrl + Spase + propro (Read Only) и т. д. (они есть в Delphi XE2 и выше) для автоматической генерации кода